# what is the mistake in the while/for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

This is the output using the wrong for/while-loop operation:

current value is 60

current value is 120

total value is 120

This is what I would like it to be:

current value is 10

current value is 30

total value is 30

```
prices = [10, 20, 30]
total = 0
steps = 0
step_limit = 2
while steps < step_limit:
    steps +=1
    for i in prices:
        total += i
    print(f'current value is {total}')
print(f'total value is {total}')
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you want to achieve? (How do you expect to calculate the desired output)

Comment: I want to sum up the numbers which are in the list of prices. But there is a step_limit of 2. So I just want to aggregate 10 and then 20. So that in the first step there is a current value of 10, than a current value of 30 and in addition I want the total aggregation or sum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add each element from the list, the problem that arises here is in the following part of your code:

```
for i in prices:
    total += i
```

This means that you iterate through each element inside the list and add it to the total (10+20+30). This is done 2 times, so the total will be 120.

You have to replace that part of the code with something that accesses only one element at a time. For instance:

```
total += prices[steps]
```

If you desire to add the last element and display the total straight away with it, you can add the last price outside of the `while` loop right before the message display at the end:

```
total += prices[steps]
print(f'total value is {total}')
```

Comment: Thank you so far. I reedited my post. But your answer helped me.

Comment: If I do what you say my Output will be:

current value is 10
current value is 30
current value is 60
total value is 60

What if I want to skip current value is 60, but nethertheless I want to see: 


current value is 10
current value is 30
total value is 60

Comment: Then you will indeed need to use ‘<‘ symbol instead of ‘<=‘ for the while loop to not take into account the last element inside of it. You will need to access the last element to add it to your total, so right after the end of while and before the last print, put once again ‘total += prices[steps]’.

Comment: Edited my answer regarding the part mentioned in your comment.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer is what you are looking for, please click the green check next to the answer. Thanks!